# outllook 2010 imap multiple accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, imap

I use Gmail settings feature to fetch email from a few different accounts to a unique main address.
Then I use outlook 2010 to download all that mail with IMAP. 
the problem is that outlook replies from that main account regardless of the address the mail was sent to. 
is there a way to force outlook to use the "From" field of whatever address the mail was sent to?

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeh outlook kinda sucks at this point. Its posible but you have to add all you different e-mail accounts as well to outlook and then you may change the send/receive setting that only your main account sends/and receives and the other accounts only sending.

If you want a better solution i would recommend you to use a different e-mail client. With Thunderbird e.g it is possible to add different smtp server for one e-mail account.

Answer (score 0):

hey thanks for the input Ivan. I searched a bit more and found a workaround in the end. I didn't want to manually having to select the sender every time. 
so I came across a macro that does exactly what I need. you can grab it here:

http://slipstick.com/developer/reply-using-address-message-sent-to/